# How to pass a value from view to model in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to edit retrieved users that am stuck here is my code

I have a function in the model that selects all the users

```
public function retrieve() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->get('UserDetails');     
    return $query->result();
}
```

In the controller the queried data is passed to view

```
public function edit_user() {
    $data['query']=$this->user_model->retrieve();
    $this->layout->view('creation/update_user',$data);
}
```

Like this

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
<a href="edit_user"><?php echo $row->username;?></a>
<?php echo $row->firstname;?></a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

I want when one clicks on the username he should be able to edit the user.
How do i get the value of the clicked username that will be passed to the

```
 $username
```

in the model (am aware CI is MVC, how can pass to controller then to model)

```
public function select_user_details() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('username' $username);
    $query=$this->db->get('users');
    return $query->result();
}
```

In the controller for editing users

```
public function edit_user() {
    $data['query']=$this->user_model->select_user_details();
    $this->layout->view('creation/update_user',$data);
}
```

In the display

```
<? foreach($query as $row)
<input type="text" name="uname"  value="<?php echo $row->username; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="name"  value="<?php echo $row->names; ?>"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter to the edit user method, and make a redirection in your controller. So, if there's no id specified, you get the list of all users, but if there is an id, you run a new model function (query with WHERE user_id = $id rather than $username) and load another view. Something like this:

```
public function edit_user($id = false) {
    if ( !$id ) {
        $data['query']=$this->user_model->retrieve();
        $this->layout->view('creation/update_user',$data);
    }
    else {
        $data['query']=$this->user_model->retrieve_one_user($id); // new model method for a single user
        $this->layout->view('creation/edit_user',$data);        // new view 
    }
}
```

And in your view, you need to make your username link go to .../edit_user/USER_ID_HERE.

You can also use different controller methods for that: like `list_users()` and `edit_user($id)`. Also, you can do it in a single view. It's really up to you and what will work best for your app. There are million ways to do it.

---

To do it with the least amount of changes, just add a parameter to the select_user_details method (as well as the edit_user method in the controller):

```
public function select_user_details($username) {
...
public function edit_user($username) {
...
```

But again, make sure that the link from the user list would go to .../select_user_details/my_username_here. Like this:

```
<a href="edit_user/<?php echo $row->username;?>"><?php echo $row->username;?></a>
```

Comment: Well i did as you suggested but on the edit option, it lists all the users in the db `'$data['query']=$this->user_model->retrieve_one_user($username);'` how should i modify `'retrieve_one_user($username)'` look like?

This is what i have `public function retrieve_one_user($staff_id){
  $this->db->select('*');  
  $query=$this->db->get('users');
  return $query->result();
 }`

Comment: Seems like you just need to put a WHERE clause there and you're good to go. Something like `$this->db->where('staff_id', $staff_id);` and instead of `return $query->result();` you can have `return $query->row();`

Comment: Actually that was issue since the start in the `$this->db->where('staff_id', $staff_id);` I get the syntax error `syntax error, unexpected '$staff_id'`

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue - can you var_dump $staff_id before that?

Comment: Thanks in my code i had messed up with this statement `$this->db->where('staff_id', $staff_id)` I forgot the comma before `$staff_id`

Answer (score 0):

In View -

```
  <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>controllerName/edit_user/<?php echo $row->username;?>"><?php echo $row->username;?></a>
    <?php echo $row->firstname;?></a>
    <?php endforeach;?>>
```

In Controller -

```
    function edit_user($userName)
    {
     $data['query']=$this->user_model->retrieve($userName);
     $this->layout->view('creation/update_user',$data);
    }
```

In Model -

```
public function retrieve($userName) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $query = $this->db->get('UserDetails');     
    return $query->result();
}
```